# Is there any way to send embed pictures through a command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I've been working on this bot for a little while, but I can't get it to send embed pictures through a command. If anyone could help me, I would be very thankful. Here is the code:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('!PNG'):
    role = get(message.server.roles, id="517064875134943262")
    userID = message.author.id
    e = discord.Embed()
    e.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/5nqpFiF.jpg")
    if not "343249790047485952" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Insufficient Permissions.')
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, e)
```

And this is what I've been getting on Discord:

discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x000000010377EEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the embed using the `embed` keyword argument, otherwise you're sending its string representation.

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=e)
```

You can see the [`Client.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped :D